# how to log the reason for resilience4j fallback in camel route

Tags: apache-camel

in resilience4j configuration I have params for circuit breaker, bulkhead and thread timeout together. Once the fallback happens, I am unable to find out what caused the fallback.I am implementing the resilience4j configuration in camel route.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix onFallback and Exception, use doTry() and  throwExceptionWhenHalfOpenOrOpenState(true) configuraton :

```
.doTry()
  .circuitBreaker()
    .resilience4jConfiguration()
        .throwExceptionWhenHalfOpenOrOpenState(true)
     .end()
     .to("http://fooservice.com/faulty")
    .end()
  .endDoTry()
  .doCatch(Exception.class)
     .log("${exception.message}")
  .end
```